# Cannot assign to property in protocol constrained to class - Swift compiler error

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, swift2

I use Xcode 7 beta 6 and I have code like this:

```
public protocol ViewForViewModel {
    typealias ViewModelType
    var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get set }
    func bindToViewModel()
}

func afterViewInstantiated <V : ViewForViewModel where V: UIViewController, V.ViewModelType: AnyObject>(view : V, viewModel: V.ViewModelType) -> V {
    //Cannot assign to property: 'view' is a 'let' constant
    view.viewModel = viewModel // error here

    VMTracker.append(viewModel, view: view)

    return view
}
```

Compiler complains on assignment `view.viewModel = viewModel`.
I'm understand what `ViewForViewModel` protocol is not constrained to class by itself, but `V` type is constrained to `UIViewController` class. Is it a bug or a feature?

UPD: it even complains about `UITableViewCell` variable:

```
func registerBinding<V: BindableCellView where V: UITableViewCell>(viewType: V.Type) {
    let typeName = nameOfType(V.ViewModelType.self)

    bindings[typeName] = { [unowned self] viewModel, indexPath in
        let view = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(V.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! V

        //Cannot assign to 'viewModel' because 'view' is a 'let' constant
        //However view is UITableViewCell that support ViewForViewModel protocol
        view.viewModel = viewModel as! V.ViewModelType

        self.onWillBind?(view, indexPath)
        view.bindToViewModel()
        self.onDidBind?(view, indexPath)

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case it should be considered an "unimplemented feature" (that the compiler cannot infer the behavior of a class in this context). So to fix it you have to make the `value` a `var`:

```
func afterViewInstantiated <V : ViewForViewModel where V: UIViewController, V.ViewModelType: AnyObject>(var view : V, viewModel: V.ViewModelType) -> V
```

In the second case you should provide more information about the error (message) and the types. Where does `V` come from?

Comment: Error is the same. BTW, I updated second example. It seems compiler look at protocol type only ignoring type what implements it.

Comment: @HeMet Do you get the same error message if you change the signature? Have you tried it in a playground?

Comment: Yes, it helps. I think It is really "unimplemented feature" what complier could not infer who supports protocol in that case. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 6):

If the Compiler can't infer, that the parameter will always be a reference type, you can always add `class` to the protocol declaration:

```
public protocol ViewForViewModel: class {
  typealias ViewModelType
  var viewModel: ViewModelType! { get set }
  func bindToViewModel()
}
```

Once the protocol is marked up like that, you should be able to assign values to the property even if the object is stored in a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler is complaining about the protocol not being able to be used as a non-generic type, delete the `typealias` in the protocol.

BTW, what is the use case for this?

Comment: No, it complains about let argument. I added error description to the post. Use case is the `MVVM` for `UIKit`. It is a part of binding mechanism for `Views` and `ViewModels`. https://github.com/HeMet/MVVMKit

Comment: Did you ever found out how to get rid of the compiler error?